# Spring Batch Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am getting this error in while running the batch job. I am very much new to Spring Batch so guys plz help as i didn't knw wht to do with this error. There is no other Batch job running in my system also .

My root-config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

<import resource="job-context.xml"/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="dataSource" /></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.qr.jadu.tx.conpoolrouter.DataSourceRouter">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="com.qr.jadu.tx.conpoolrouter.TransactionTypes">
            <entry key="RO" value-ref="schedules-read-dataSource" />
            <entry key="RW" value-ref="schedules-write-dataSource" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="schedules-read-dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="masters-read-dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/masterDatabase"/>
</bean>
<bean id="schedules-read-dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/scheduleDatabase"/>
</bean>

<bean id="schedules-write-dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/scheduleDatabase"/>
</bean>

<bean id="security-read-dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/sysDs"/>
</bean>

<bean id="csp-read-dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/cspDatabase"/>
</bean>


<bean id="schedules-punitpostprocessor" class="com.qr.jadu.entity.helper.JaduPersistenceUnitPostProcessor">
    <property name="locationPatterns">
    <list>
            <value>classpath*:com/croamis/**/*.class</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

 <alias name="schedules-dataSource" alias="lov-dataSource"/>


<bean id="schedules-entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <value>com.croamis.schedules</value>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="schedulesPU" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="schedules-punitpostprocessor" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
    <!--  To run with MySQL -->
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
        </props>
    <!--  To run with Oracle -->
    <!--
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>            
    --> 
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="schedules-entityManagerFactory" />

</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My job-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema  /batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<job id="GenerateOperationalFlightJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet task-executor="taskexecutor">
            <chunk reader="ScheduleRecordsAdapter" processor="scheduleRecordProcessor" writer="operationalFlightWriter"  commit-interval="1">

        </chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
```

```
   <bean id="ScheduleRecordsAdapter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.adapter.ItemReaderAdapter">
   <property name="targetObject" ref="scheduleRecordsRetrievalAdapter"/>
   <property name="targetMethod" value="getScheduleRecord"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
     <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jobLauncher"     class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">  
  <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />    
 </bean> 

  </beans>
```

Comment: Can we get some insight into how the DataSourceRouter works?